# NHibernate Oracle - Transaction Commit Issue

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

0  vote down

Hi,

I am running with same Issue of at the time of Commit transaction it fails. I have changed my all mapping string with AnsiString. But still i am getting error.

Select is working fine, even delete is also working fine.

If my transaction contains only one insert statement or update statement then also it is working fine.

But when there are more than one queries (Insert/Update) then at the time of commit it is giving me error that "Integrity Constraint: Parent Key not found"

Can you please help me out?

Mahesh....

Comment: How have you mapped the entity?  Is there a HasMany relationship or some other association?

Answer (score 0):

this error is an integrity constraint error. It means that at the end of your transaction a child that has no parent in a parent-child relationship. Since you are getting this error on commit it means the `FOREIGN KEY` is declared as `DEFERRABLE` (initialy deferred) and only checks for integrity at commit time.

You have a problem in your logic, perhaps you could post a simple example (CREATE TABLE parent... CREATE TABLE child... UPDATE/INSERT) and we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate does the insert (or update) of your employee **before** inserting the newly created employee_type. The error means that your employee is missing its employee_type in database.

2 choices:

1. Do a ISession.Flush after creating the employee_type and before creating (or updateing) your employee.
2. Change the foreign key to be deferable.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution ....

It is happening with me because of NHibernate Behaviour...

I have explicitely created Sequence and Triggers for autoincrement.

but it will fire two time, first when i did normal save and second when i call transaction complete. So there is miss match between id's actual used and referenced.

So it is giving me error - parent key not found.

I have just removed all the trigger and sequences and in the mapping file i have added generated class as a increment. :D

" generator class="increment" "

It is perfectly works for me...

Thanks,
Mahesh